# ASP.NET Redirect user to current custom domain after Azure Active Directory Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, redirect, active-directory

I am trying to redirect my users to the domain on which they tried to access my website before being redirected to the Azure Active Directory login page. I am using OpenIDConnect, and the following is the bit of code that defines the URI on which the user needs to be redirected post-login :

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                    {
                        string appBaseUrl = "https://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase + context.Request.Uri.PathAndQuery;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase + context.Request.Uri.PathAndQuery;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },

                    //custom validation
                    SecurityTokenValidated = onValidate,
                    AuthenticationFailed = onFailure
                }
```

The issue I am having is that I have custom domains and `context.Request.Host` returns the generic domain of my website instead of what I need.

For instance, I have my website and 2 custom domains :

- `mywebsite.azurewebsites.net` the generic host
- `mywebsite.customdomain1.com`
- `mywebsite.customdomain2.com`

When connecting from `mywebsite.customdomain1.com`, `context.Request.Host` is equal to `mywebsite.azurewebsites.net`. Not knowing which domain my users come from, I am forced to redirect them to a unique domain ... which is not very ideal.

What are my options here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating on my issue, the problem came from the fact that I use CDN to provide access my website from `customdomain1` and `customdomain2`. The CDN was badly configured and did not let through the original hostname from the request it received. I changed the configuration and everything works now.